# CoreData with Relationship and attributes in relation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I can't figure it out. How does CoreData implement JOIN known from SQL?

Let's say I have `EntityA (attr1, attr2)` and `EntityB(attr3, attr4)`.
Now I want to set up relationship on `EntityA.attr1 = EntityB.attr3`

I don't see a place to define which attributes should be used with relation.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the relationships are defined in the xcdatamodel page.

The relationship objects are returned in an NSSet which you can then manipulate using an NSarray.

```
NSSet *set = [object valueForKey:@"relationship"]; 
NSArray *relationships = [set allObjects];
```

Comment: thanks. I get the concept wrong. Now I know that relation key is actually hidden, and it's not relation key as you get it with SQL.